# Play a sound in actionscript

Tags: audio, actionscript

I am currently trying to write code for actionscript that will play a sound. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, however I need to play the sound with the stipulation that it doesn't begin playing until after the sound is finished loading. Is there a way to make sure the sound is loaded before I play it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound(); 
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
sound.load(new URLRequest("mySound.mp3")); 

function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    var loadedSound:Sound = event.target as Sound; 
    loadedSound.play();
}
```

This is taken from [this adobe tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d25.html).

Good luck coding!